# Read HSV value of pixel in opencv

Tags: opencv, pixel, hsv

how would you go about reading the pixel value in HSV format rather than RGB? The code below reads the pixel value of the circles' centers in RGB format. Is there much difference when it comes to reading value in HSV?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //load image from directory
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\SnookerPic.png");


    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //covert to grayscale
    cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
    cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);

    IplImage* canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    IplImage* rgbcanny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    cvCanny(gray, canny, 50, 100, 3);

    //detect circles
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 35.0, 75, 60,0,0);
    cvCvtColor(canny, rgbcanny, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    //draw all detected circles
    for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
    {
         // round the floats to an int
         float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
         cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));
         int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
         //uchar* ptr;
         //ptr = cvPtr2D(img, center.y, center.x, NULL);
         //printf("B: %d G: %d R: %d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);
         CvScalar s;

         s = cvGet2D(img,center.y, center.x);//colour of circle
        printf("B: %f G: %f R: %f\n",s.val[0],s.val[1],s.val[2]);

         // draw the circle center
         cvCircle(img, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

         // draw the circle outline
         cvCircle(img, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );

         //display coordinates
         printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius);

    }

    //create window
    //cvNamedWindow("circles", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("SnookerImage", 1);
    //show image in window
    //cvShowImage("circles", rgbcanny);
    cvShowImage("SnookerImage", img);

    cvSaveImage("out.png", img);
    //cvDestroyWindow("SnookerImage");
    //cvDestroyWindow("circles");
    //cvReleaseMemStorage("storage");
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the C++ interface, you can use

```
cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

See [the documentation for cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) for more information.

**Update:**

Reading and writing pixels the slow way (assuming that the HSV values are stored as a `cv::Vec3b` ([doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#vec)))

```
cv::Vec3b pixel = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0); // read pixel (0,0) (make copy)
pixel[0] = 0; // H
pixel[1] = 0; // S
pixel[2] = 0; // V
image.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) = pixel; // write pixel (0,0) (copy pixel back to image)
```

Using the `image.at<...>(x, y)` ([doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat), scroll down a lot) notation is quite slow, if you want to manipulate every pixel. There is an article in the [documentation on how to access the pixels faster](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/fast_element_access.html). You can apply the iterator method also like this:

```
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it = image.begin<cv::Vec3b>(),
                    it_end = image.end<cv::Vec3b>();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    // work with pixel in here, e.g.:
    cv::Vec3b& pixel = *it; // reference to pixel in image
    pixel[0] = 0; // changes pixel in image
}
```

Comment: i understand i can convert the image to HSv but how do I extract pixel value in HSV format

Comment: You should be more explicit in your question about where your problem is. I assumed that you knew how to access the elements of a `cv::Mat` since you seemed to be able to read the pixels in RGB format.

Comment: i have added the code i have wrote to read the pixel value in RGB. looks a lot different than what you have suggested. Any way it can be done similar to the way i have written it for RGB? thanks

Comment: OpenCV does not expose a bgr2hsv(CvScalar&) function. You have to write one yourself.