# opencv java, how to get hsv values from each pixel

Tags: java, android, opencv

I found an answer by C++ at here [Read HSV value of pixel in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859196/read-hsv-value-of-pixel-in-opencv)

```
cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::Vec3b pixel = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0); // I don't know the equivalent method in Java
pixel[0] = 0; // H
pixel[1] = 0; // S
pixel[2] = 0; // V`
```

but I don't know how to get done by Java ?

Comment: Read the java API for OpenCV, anyways it is `Imgproc.cvtColor()`.

Comment: cv::Vec3b pixel = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0); I didn't find the equivalent method in Java

Comment: In java you won't get `cv::Vec3b`, instead it returns a `double[]` array, to get the array you may use: `image.get(0, 0)`, provided the `image` is a `Mat` object.